# Rails Controller Testing - RSpec - Updating 'many' associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

I have  Controller update action for my `room` model, where I am looking to update all other `rooms` that `belong_to` to the same user. `room belongs_to user`, `user has_many rooms`.

The spec is failing - I am less confident with Controller testing than any other testing so wanted to check whether my approach is correct. Is this the most appropriate to go about updating other associated records or is there a better way?

---

#### Controller

```
def update
    I18n.with_locale(params[:locale]) do
      Room.transaction do
        @room = Room.find(params[:id], lock: true)
        @room_presenter = RoomPresenter.new(@room)
        .......

        @room.update_attributes!(params.require(:room).permit!)
      end
      update_all_host_rooms_cancellation_policy(@room.cancellation_policy)
    end
    ..........
  end

  def update_all_host_rooms_cancellation_policy(cancellation_policy)
    if params[:apply_cancellation_policy_to_all].present?
      @room.user.rooms.not_in(@room).all.each do |room|
        room.update(cancellation_policy: cancellation_policy)
        admin_log(current_admin_user.login, params[:controller], params[:action], @room)
      end
    end
  end
```

---

#### Spec

```
  describe "#update_all_host_rooms_cancellation_policy(cancellation_policy)" do
    let(:host) { create(:user, :validated_host, host_badge: "certified") }
    let(:room) { create(:room, host: host) }
    let(:second_room) { create(:room, host: host) }

    it "applies the selected policy to all other properties owned by the host" do
      put :update, id: room.id, room: {cancellation_policy: "strict", apply_cancellation_policy_to_all: "1"}
      expect(room.reload.cancellation_policy).to eq "strict"
      expect(second_room.reload.cancellation_policy).to eq "strict"
    end
```

---

#### Associated view snippet with the checkbox

```
  <label class="checkbox">
    <%= check_box_tag :apply_cancellation_policy_to_all, "1", params[:apply_cancellation_policy_to_all] %>
    <%= label_tag "apply_cancellation_policy_to_all", "Apply cancellation policy to all" %>
  </label>
```

---

Finally just to explain the thinking behind the test:

I create a host with valid attributes.

```
let(:host) { create(:user, :validated_host, host_badge: "certified") }
```

Create two rooms belong to the host. Be explicit in ensuring that `cancellation_policy: "standard"` for clarity. As this is what I am updating.

```
let(:room) { create(:room, user: host, cancellation_policy: "standard") }
let(:second_room) { create(:room, user: host, cancellation_policy: "standard") }
```

Make the put request to call the update action - passing in the room_id, with the nested room params hash setting `cancellation_policy:"strict"` and `apply_cancellation_policy_to_all: "1"` (e.g. setting the checkbox).

```
it "applies the selected policy to all other properties owned by the host" do
  put :update, {id: room.id, room: {cancellation_policy: "strict", apply_cancellation_policy_to_all: "1"}}
```

This should have updated the `cancellation_policy` to `strict` on my first room that was passed in as the `room.id`. So I write my expectation for that:

```
  expect(room.reload.cancellation_policy).to eq "strict"
```

The call in the update action to `#update_all_host_rooms_cancellation_policy(cancellation_policy)` should be triggered and the `second_room` which also belongs to the Factory `host` should also be set to `strict`

```
  expect(second_room.reload.cancellation_policy).to eq "strict"
end
```

---

Finally the test failure which is failing on the initial room (i.e. - `expect(room.reload.cancellation_policy).to eq "strict"`)

```
   expected: "strict"
   got: "standard"
```

---

The code is working in my local environment - but failing the spec - so just trying to understand this from a testing perspective.

Comment: what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Also - have you used pry or puts statements to make sure that you are executing the code you think you should be? eg `def update_all_host_rooms_cancellation_policy(cancellation_policy)
    if params[:apply_cancellation_policy_to_all].present?
      puts "we have apply_cancellation_policy_to_all"
      room_set = @room.user.rooms.not_in(@room).all
     puts "trying ot apply it against rooms: #{room_set}"
      room_set.each do |room|
        puts "trying ot apply it to room: #{room}"
        room.update(cancellation_policy: cancellation_policy)
` etc etc

Comment: (sorry, comment code-formatting is awful... but hopefully that gives you an idea of how you can see what's really going on when you run the spec)

Comment: Thanks Taryn  - will take a look at this now. I have edited my question with the rspec failure.

Comment: right, so not much to go on.  Have a go running it with the puts statements to give you an idea of what path is being executed and if it's what you expect (heh) :)

Comment: Cheers - the code is executing as expected - its just the test that is failing but I have taken your advice and used the puts statements which makes me alot clearer about it all.

Comment: So each of the rooms is hitting the LOC: `room.update(cancellation_policy: cancellation_policy)` ? have you put a puts before and after to check that the `cancellation_policy` field actually got saved? have you tried `it_worked = room.update(...` then `puts "did it work? #{it_worked}"` ? to check that the update actually did save? and if it didn't work... have a look at the errors on `room` ?

Comment: Thanks for all of your Taryn. I tried all the above and the code is working as expected with a sample data set of staging. I am seeing all puts in the server logs. It's just the tests that are failing. Just going to delete the specs :(